# r Shiny action button and data table output

Tags: r, shiny

I would like an output data table after selection of some simple criteria, once an action button is clicked.

The code works without the action button as an input. As soon as I include the `observeEvent` function, the result is no longer generated. See example code below.

Note: Removing the line `observeEvent(input$gobutton,{` and the corresponding `})` will produce the correct output.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(6,div(checkboxGroupInput("test1", "Testing buttons", 
                                           choices=c("A","B","C"),
                                           selected=c("A","B","C"))))),

  hr(),

  actionButton("gobutton","Start"),

  dataTableOutput("summary_table")

)

server <- function(input,output){

  output$summary_table <- renderDataTable({

    observeEvent(input$gobutton,{

    df=data.frame(col1=input$test1,col2=seq(1,length(input$test1),1))

    df
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wrap it in a `eventReactive` instead:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(6,div(checkboxGroupInput("test1", "Testing buttons", 
                                           choices=c("A","B","C"),
                                           selected=c("A","B","C"))))),

  hr(),
  actionButton("gobutton","Start"),
  dataTableOutput("summary_table")

)

server <- function(input,output){

  data <- eventReactive(input$gobutton,{
    if(is.null(input$test1)){
      return()
    }

    df <- data.frame(col1=input$test1,col2=seq(1,length(input$test1),1))
    df
  })

  output$summary_table <- renderDataTable({
    data()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. Do you have any idea why `observeEvent` doesn't work, but `eventReactive` does?

Comment: An observer is like a reactive expression in that it can read reactive values and call reactive expressions, and will automatically re-execute when those dependencies change. But unlike reactive expressions, it `doesn't yield a result` and can't be used as an input to other reactive expressions. Thus, observers are only useful for their side effects (for example, performing I/O). https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observe.html